# Why Immer didn't return me a new state even if I modified the draft?

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

I don't know why even I have modified the draft, immer didn't provide me with a new state, but the old state instance with modified content.

```
import CartItem from "../../models/cart-item";
import * as actions from "../actions/actionTypes";
import produce from "immer"


const initialState = [];

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actions.ADD_TO_CART:
          const {id, title, price} = action.product;
          const itemIndexInCart = state.findIndex(item => item.id === id);

          const nextState = produce(state, draftState => {
            if (itemIndexInCart === -1) {
              draftState.push(new CartItem(id, 1, price, title, price));
            } else {
              draftState[itemIndexInCart]['quantity']++;
              draftState[itemIndexInCart]['sum'] += price;
            }
          });
          console.log(state === nextState);
          return nextState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default reducer;
```

It is working when new item is pushing into the array, but it is not working as expected when I want to modify the quantity and sum of the array item. The log show me it's the same object under that circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you should find the item id from the `draftState` within `produce` callback. In `produce` callback, try `const itemIndexInCart = draftState.findIndex(item => item.id === id);` right before the condition

Comment: No, it didn't work, actually the nextState is updated, but somehow it share the memory reference to the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to make your class *immerable*, according to the [docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/complex-objects).
Notice that console.logging a draft might print "null", even though this object is not null.

```
import {immerable} from "immer"

class Foo {
    [immerable] = true // Option 1

    constructor() {
        this[immerable] = true // Option 2
    }
}

Foo[immerable] = true // Option 3
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-resonance-v6v9b?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Note that [**you should *never* put non-serializable values like class instances into the Redux store**](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-put-non-serializable-values-in-state-or-actions).

In addition, you *should* be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which will let you simplify your existing Redux logic.  For example, this reducer could be written as:

```js
const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addToCart(state, action) {
      const {id, title, price} = action.payload;
      const item = state.find(item => item.id === id);
      
      if(item) {
        item.quantity++;
        item.sum += price;
      } else {
        state.push({id, price, title, quantity: 1});
      }
    }
  }
})
```